# How to check when two object collisions

Tags: java, android, collision

I have two moving image views in a little game I'm making,
anyway they are always in the same Y so im just want to check when they are in the same x
any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int [] object1Position = new int[2];  // declare int array for x,y object position
int [] object2Position = new int[2];  // the same

imageView1.getLocationOnScreen(object1Position); // get imageView1 position
imageView2.getLocationOnScreen(object2Position); // get imageView2 position

public boolean checkColisionOnXAxis()
{
    if (object1Position[0] == object2Position[0] )
       return true;
    return false;
}
```

just an idea.. but you need to get at each time the current location of the objects.. 
so you need timer or something like that to get the current position

Comment: tnx i tried that but it seems like its no working when i try to do somthing if the images collisions and no work

Comment: I see, what you want is to detect if those images are colliding and then move one or both of them to other direction?

Comment: i want to check when the both image have the same x, anyway i succeded